# Docker Continuous Integration with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-integration, containers, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm currently trying to automate our dev process using CodePipeline. My docker application fetches from the Source(Github) -> Builds(AWS CodeBuild) -> Deploy. In the final deployment process, I'm having trouble revising my task definition and restarting my cluster tasks. I understand that I need a CloudFormation template to perform these actions, but there isn't much documentation on how I can accomplish the deployment process by using CloudFormation(revising my task definition and updating my tasks). Could there be another way to autonomously deploy my containers via AWS?

Comment: Where are you deployed?  The Amazon EC2 Container Service can deploy Docker containers pretty easily though there is a little bit of scripting to update the services.

Comment: I'm trying to deploy to EC2 Container Service. I understand that I have to update the task definition and point the service to the new image that was deployed. Is there an existing template that allows me to trigger CloudFormation that will do the updating of service for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deployed your original service from CloudFormation then CloudFormation makes it incredibly easy to deploy a new Task Definition onto ECS.

Here is a good starter for how CloudFormation will deploy services for you onto the EC2 Container Service: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ecs.html

Once you have it all deployed from CloudFormation you have 2 options for the deployment:
1) Update the CloudFormation template with the new deployment pieces that you need and it will create a change set for you and update your stack.
2) Only use CloudFormation to deploy the service and put the task definition as a parameter. This will allow you to just modify the inputs to the stack instead of updating the entire thing every time.

CloudFormation will automatically try and do a blue/green deployment for you when you update it within the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the help Davis. Just to re-iterate, I should use this template to manage my ECS Instances/Containers/Images, and use it in my pipeline. But is there anyway that I can modify this script or are there any existing scripts that will restart my tasks to point to the :latest image?

Comment: The way that I have done it in the past is to use one CF template to build out the ECS Cluster and one template for each service that I wanted to deploy.

When you want to update your service to the latest task definition/docker image you change the CF to point to the lastest ECR image/task definition (whichever you make into a parameter for the template). CF will then deploy it for you. You can do this from the console or via the CLI and script into a CI/CD pipeline.

I personally prefer making the ECR image the parameter because it will update and redeploy the task definition for you

Comment: I think I have all my pieces together, the only thing I'm missing is a CF template that will point my task definition to the latest revision upon a successful build, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error with different methods, the best way to update your ECS Task Definitions and service is to directly update them through the AWS CLI in your post_build section of your buildspec.yml through AWS CodeBuild. You can even use the environment variable that is set using the commit ID to keep track of the tag of each images!

Answer (score 0):

For the scenario that you described, you may want to try this sample https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-refarch-continuous-deployment

Comment: Thanks for the help! Not sure if you've used this before, but will the service.yaml script allow the task definitions to be re-defined to point to the latest image build?